# Send gtag event from cross domain to parent domain

Tags: javascript, iframe, google-analytics, gtag.js

I'm trying to setup a `send event` from a `iframe` originated on my domain and placed on other domain (not mine). I placed the analytics code on the `iframe`.

```
<script async src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=UA-XXXXXXXX-XX"></script>
<script>
  window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
  function gtag(){dataLayer.push(arguments);}
  gtag('js', new Date());

  gtag('config', 'UA-XXXXXXXX-XX',{ 'anonymize_ip': true });
</script>
```

Bellow that analytics code (with the `UA-XXXXXXXX-XX` from my `parentdomain.com`), I do a check to see if the iframe **is not on** my `parentdomain.com` and then, I set the `tracker` attribute to the **div id** `ads_close`:

```
<script>
ref = document.referrer;
whitelist = ["parentdomain.com"];
match = false;

for( var i = whitelist.length - 1; i >= 0; i-- ) {

 if( ref.indexOf( whitelist[ i ] ) > -1 ) { match = true; }

}
// If is not the parent domain, then add the onClick atributte to the ID "ads_close"
if( ! match ) {

  refer = document.referrer;
  var str1 ="gtag(\'event\', \'External\', {\'event_category\': \'yes\',\'event_label\': ";
  var str2 = "'";  
  var str3 = refer;
  var str4 = "'";
  var str5 = "});";
  var tracker = str1.concat(str2) + str3 + str4 + str5;
ads_close.setAttribute("onClick", tracker);

 }
</script>
```

The above code renders this way, **IF NOT**, on `parentdomain.com`:

```
<div class="adspop_close" id="adspop_close" onclick="gtag('event', 'Externos', {'event_category': 'yes','event_label': 'https://www.theotherdomain.com/post/'});"></div>
```

**The problem:**

Every time i click on the the div with the ID **`adspop_close`**, I cannot see the event on my `parentdomain.com` google analytics account...

**The question:**

What am'I doing wrong?

Comment: Your question is not clear. Which domain shows the pop-up? How are you planning to measure an event on another website even if it's inside an iframe?

Comment: The iframe **is not placed** on my `parentdomain.com`. The iframe **is placed on** `otherdomain.com`. How am'I planning to measure it? The answer is by implementing the code above as stated, unless I'm doing something wrong...

Comment: Did you check whether the request is properly sent?

Comment: @Twistingnether , how? It doesn't work with this implementation and it's driving me crazy...

Comment: The browser should send a request like this https://www.google-analytics.com/r/collect?...

Comment: @Twistingnether, please explain how can I test that.

Comment: Open developers tools with F12, then go to the Network tab and check whether you see a request when clicking on the div

Comment: @Twistingnether, this is what I get once I click the div: `www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js:1 Failed to load resource: net::ERR_BLOCKED_BY_CLIENT
28254:214 Uncaught TypeError: gtag is not a function
    at HTMLDivElement.onclick (28254:214)
onclick @ 28254:214
28254:214 Uncaught TypeError: gtag is not a function
    at HTMLBodyElement.onclick (28254:214)`. 28254 is part of the URL of my iframe source like this: `src="https://www.example.com/embed/28254` See if it helps...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you try to track data from the iframe itself it will appear as if the interaction is happening on another domain in another session, which is what I think you're trying to avoid. If you want to track interactions in an iframe and act as if they were part of the parent container then the best way is by using [postMessage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/postMessage) to communicate the event to the parent, where it can be handled naturally. The containing page does not have script access to the iframe for security reasons, but the iframe can send communicate to the containing page via postMessage.

### solution 1

The [Google Development Guide](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/cross-domain) shows us an approach for this cross-domain interaction (scroll down to the IFRAME section).

To link the interactions into the same session you need to share client id's. Unortunately, iframes typically initalize with the HTML of the page, long before google tracking has the client ID ready. So we can't just pass it on load, but need to wait for everything and then use postMessage.

Here's the containing page code example:

```html
<iframe id="destination-frame" src="https://destination.com"></iframe>

<script>
ga('create', 'UA-XXXXX-Y', 'auto');
ga(function(tracker) {
  // Gets the client ID of the default tracker.
  var clientId = tracker.get('clientId');

  // Gets a reference to the window object of the destionation iframe.
  var frameWindow = document.getElementById('destination-frame').contentWindow;

  // Sends the client ID to the window inside the destination frame.
  frameWindow.postMessage(clientId, 'https://destination.com');
});
</script>
```

And here's the listener that would be in the iframe:

```
window.addEventListener('message', function(event) {
  // Ignores messages from untrusted domains.
  if (event.origin != 'https://destination.com') return;

  ga('create', 'UA-XXXXX-Y', 'auto', {
    clientId: event.data
  });
});
```

That page also has some extra logic to handle the situation where a client id never comes through postMessage. If you need to pass through the 'UA' string as well and wait to initialize gtag in the iframe completely, that's doable as well. Once you recieve the data you need, initialize gtag and track away. You won't need to rewrite any DOM.

### solution 2

You can invert the logic of the postMessage communication instead. Rather than doing any tracking in the iframe at all, you can set up any events to trigger a postMessage instead, passing the information like category, action, and label up to the containing page. In the containing page you would add a listener for the postMessage and handle it by triggering a gtag event.

For instance, from the iframe:

```html
<script>
  try {
    var postObject = JSON.stringify({
      event: 'iframeClickEvent', 
      category: 'someCategory',
      action: 'someAction',
      label: 'someLabel'
    });
    parent.postMessage(postObject, 'https://www.YOURWEBSITE.com');
  } catch(e) {
    window.console && window.console.log(e);
  }
</script>
```

and the containing page:

```js
window.addEventListener('message', function(message) {
  try{
    var data = JSON.parse(message.data);
    var dataLayer = window.dataLayer || (window.dataLayer = []);
    if (data.event === 'iframeClickEvent') {
      dataLayer.push({ 'event': 'someEvent', .... });
    }
  } catch(e){}
});
```